# TextEdit’s "Orientation Layout"

Tags: services, textedit, shortcut-menu

Just discovered a very nice feature of `Services` on the context menu.  In TextEdit, selecting Orientation Layout→Vertical rotates the text and characters 90° clockwise, keeping the window geometry the same.  All the text, regardless of what is or isn’t selected.

For a European language, not particularly useful.  But in Chinese, Japanese, or Korean, the glyphs remain upright as their reading order changes to the old traditional style (glyphs top-to bottom, lines right-to-left).

In what OS version was this feature released?  It is not available in at least one third-party app (DeepL)—are there other non-Apple apps that use it?

Update: Answer on "other apps" is on another stack: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/39044/which-word-processors-and-websites-support-vertical-writing-of-chinese

Still interested in how long it has been in MacOS.

Comment: It's also under Format > Make Layout Vertical.

Comment: Note that deepl is an Electron app, aka a web page running inside its own version of Chrome. It barely uses Cocoa and should not be taken as an indicator of what macOS can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In what OS version was this feature released?

According to Apple's developer pages, the `setLayoutOrientation(_:)` instance method of `NSTextView` was introduced in OS X 10.7.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1449483-setlayoutorientation

This review of TextEdit in Lion mentions the vertical layout option.

https://appleinsider.com/articles/11/04/08/inside_mac_os_x_10_7_lion_textedit_adds_vertical_layout_graphical_toolbar

The feature most likely comes 'for free' with the View, as do other things like Spelling and Speech.

TextEdit is essentially just a showcase implementation of `NSTextView`.